# Should I use PhoneGap instead of ramping up on the Android SDK?

Tags: android, cordova

Although I am comfortable with Java, I have much more experience with web development. I am looking to get into programming simple Android games.

Should I just program everything using Javascript/HTML and forget ramping up on Java/Android SDK? I guess my question really is, what are the limitations of PhoneGap? What are some things to consider, etc.?

Some advantages I can think of:

- More selection in terms of game engines for HTML5/JS
- Faster ramp up time
- Automatically deploy to all major platforms

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The biggest pro for phonegap is that it takes advantage of your web development experience.  I think what most people seem to miss (or ignore) is that **there is no advantage in avoiding phonegap for an android only application**!  You can still write as much native code as you want to, mixing and matching phonegap as you please.

I am writing an Android app that uses text to speech.  Because Phonegap doesn't support this in their API, you might think that Phonegap is a bad choice, but actually it was quite easy to call the Java code I need from javascript:

Java code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   //boilerplate and TTS set up
    ...
    this.appView.addJavascriptInterface(this.speak, "speak");
    ...
}

public void speak(String text) {
    this.tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
```

Javascript code:

```
speak.say("hello world");
```

Comment: i totally agree with you but the phonegap project that i'm workin on renders slow. Its performance is slow as compared with native apps does any1 have solution.

Comment: wtf black magic is this? Javascript calling java functions. awesome

Answer (score 11):

Pros for Phonegap:

- deploys to all major mobile devices
- sounds like it best fits your skillset
- covers most available platform APIs with a uniform code base, no need to learn each one
- PhoneGap Build (https://build.phonegap.com/) and Cordova (https://github.com/brianleroux/Cordova) are making it even easier to deploy to multiple platforms

Pros for Android:

- Better performance
- No limitations on which APIs you can use (i.e., video)
- Defined toolset and workflow
- native UI components
- Fragments API and native layouts make handling different screen sizes easier

It really comes down to whether or not you want to be an Android-only developer or not.  That first pro for phonegap is HUGE is you plan to develop for multiple platforms.

Answer (score 9):

I personally have major concerns over PhoneGap apps performance compared to that of a native Android app. The admittedly small amount of testing that I have done makes the PhoneGap version feel very unresponsive compared to native. I don't see how this doesn't translate to a poor user experience. Even PhoneGaps packaged sample application runs poorly.

I was very excited at the possibilities that PhoneGap appeared to open up, but I don't feel like it's there yet. I don't feel comfortable committing to a large project on PhoneGap.

Answer (score 2):

No WAY!  Adobe has their cloud build which has a 9.5 MB file size limit.  And, they are discontinuing support for other types of build.

Answer (score 1):

I have just spent the past week or so developing a simple Android app using PhoneGap. My great hope was to be able to recommend this product for use in our department as a "write-once, deploy everywhere solution."

In practice, it was more complicated than I would have hoped. I did manage to get an Android version of the app done, but I found a lot of quirks in using basic stuff like getting it to include css and the jquery mobile framework. I kept thinking that this was just my learning curve but a lot of the tutorials I found online were outdated and didn't work in the version I downloaded. The biggest surprise was that you can't link to external documents without using a plugin such as childBrowser, which is a huge drawback.

I tried today to port my app over to iOS and could not get past step one with importing css. I couldn't find any support documentation on this basic step. It's frustrating because this is a simple app that I could craft as native in Xcode in a day or so. It looks like it will take me a lot longer using PhoneGap.

PhoneGap looks really promising, but at the moment I don't want to use it. It's just a question of time. Why would I want to take twice as long on something? It might be a better choice in future versions